# CSS a:visited doesn't work for https links in IE 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, https, hyperlink

I have a strange CSS issue with IE (10, 9, 8) where a:visited won't work for https links.  It works fine with http links, however.  The color of the visited https links change while on the page, but if you refresh the page, or navigate away then back, the color change doesn't persist.  Are there any ways to work around this issue in the style sheet?

Thanks!

Comment: IMO visited and non-visited links should be the same color, as it's less confusing to the user what is clickable and what isn't.

Comment: Maybe, the problem has to do with security issues. Look at this answer in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331688/why-doesnt-this-avisited-css-style-work

Comment: Do the target HTTPS pages include "no-cache" directives that would prevent them from going into the browser history?

Comment: @Don The slight color change to the visited links is necessary because it is a table with hundreds of links to medical slides.  The user may become confused about which he or she has already viewed.  Thanks.

Comment: @Fabio-s I don't think it is a security issue as it functions correctly in the latest version of Chrome and Firefox.  Thanks.

Comment: @EricLaw I don't see any "no-cache" directives in the HTTPS pages.  Thanks.

Comment: Caching directives appear in the HTTP headers; did you check there? Got a repro URL we could look at?