# a: visited img { display: none; }

Tags: html, css

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<article class="post">
  <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img width="200" height="100" src="some.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail">
  </a>
  <header>
    <h2 class="posttitle">
      <a href="#">Posttitle</a>
    </h2>
  </header>
</article>
```

The image inside the first link only need to be displayed, when the link isn't visited yet. If the link is visited, I'll do a display: none;

```
a:visited img {
  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden !important;
  border: 1px solid red; * this is for testing*
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/rj394/2

But the image is still displayed. The testing-border is red. If I change :visited to :hover it does the display as it should (:hover and it's gone). Firebus tells me, that the image is 'display: none' but apparently it isn't...

Does someone know this problem and knows a possible solution?

Comment: Can you reproduce it at http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: You can't reffeer to elements like this in CSS ... he needs to be next or be a children of the a tag

Comment: The image is a child of the anchor.

Comment: JSfiddle won't be usefull, or, i don't know how to 'visit' a page from jsFiddle iframes.

Comment: It works in the fiddle. The Posttitle link is purple.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your CSS, but it won't work. This is a [security feature](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8331950/1679849).

Comment: Great find, but why is your answer not in an answer?

Comment: @isherwood Good question. For some odd reason my answers are being posted up here. I'm definitely not using the comment box to write them :-(

Comment: Ah. Answers that are too short and lack code or links are sometimes moved by the system.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage please see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/152859). You should see "Trivial answer converted to comment". (one time only, so don't look for it now) (oh, never mind, I see you already [reported it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208033/152859) :))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According with the documentation from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited):

> For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit the styles you can apply
>   using an element selected by this pseudo-class: only color,
>   background-color, border-color, border-bottom-color,
>   border-left-color, border-right-color, border-top-color,
>   outline-color, column-rule-color, fill and stroke. Note also that the
>   alpha component will be ignored: the alpha component of the
>   not-visited rule is used instead (except when the opacity is 0, in
>   that case the whole color is ignored, and the one of the not-visited
>   rule is used.
>
> Though the color can be changed, the method getComputedStyle will lie
>   and always give back the value of the non-visited color.

So, you can't change the `display` value. You can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6d5gF/) as how is working with a different propery as `border-color`.

You will have to use another approach as JavaScript + LocalStorage (mostly [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage)).

A **roughly** solution could be, using jQuery:

```
$("a").on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    localStorage.setItem($this.attr('href'), true);
    $this.addClass('visited');
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("a").each(function(index, elem){
        var item = $(elem);
        if (localStorage.getItem(item.attr('href'))){
            item.addClass('visited');
        }
    });
});
```

A demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NyKqM/).

Comment: For the JS solution, one could use local storage for storing which links have been visited. This would, of course, not be a good solution for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

beacus of `:visited` saved in browsers, so
you can set [Cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) for each `<a>` that clicked by javascript, and hide the `<img` inside.