# Making links :active

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got I would say rather small problem consider with adding atribute :active to some links on my website. I wrote code where I use jquery tabs where content is loaded via #div tags

For example I click on position "Home" in my menu and its conected to div #home etc
I want to make active link bold but when I use

> sidemenu li a:active { font-weight:bold; }

bolded text appears only when I hold my left mouse button on it.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Could you clarify, what is your problem?

Comment: So you mean it links to a `#section` in the page?

Comment: Links are `:active` during "[the time between the user presses the mouse button and releases it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)". You might consider using a class to indicate the current tab.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:visited` instead:

```
.sidemenu li a:visited { font-weight:bold; }
```

**EDIT**

To make only the active tab bolded, you will need to use JavaScript. Here is an example:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="tab">Tab 1</div>
<a href="#" class="tab">Tab 2</div>
<a href="#" class="tab">Tab 3</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.tab').click(function(){
    $('.tab').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zta960jk/).

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't show any effect on my link

Comment: I wonder if `sidemenu` is one of those [new-fangled whizz-bang HTML9 elements](http://html9responsiveboilerstrapjs.com/) I've been hearing about...

Comment: @JaredFarrish I think its HTML10

Comment: @GPJethro Some CSS rules cannot be set for the `:visited` selector. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8331950/1096470

Comment: This will make all visited links bold, but the OP wants only the tab being viewed to be bold.

Comment: I've got something like this in my menu:
<li><a href="#1" >  random name </a></li>

and i connect this element with div #1

in other words, when the div#1 is loaded i want to make link to it in my menu bolded, if some rules cannot be set, are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add a class to your `li` in order to make it bold. If your using jQuery you could use it to toggle the class.

http://jsfiddle.net/hawaiianchimp/my3p9bc0/1/

```
<li class="nav"><a id="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li class="nac"><a id="other" href="#other">Other</a></li>

<script>
$("li").on('click', function(){
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
.active {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jethro,

You say `"bolded text only appears when I hold my left mouse button"`. Well, that's the intended function of `:active`, i.e. the mouse button is activating the link. For other mouse events, you can try the following pseudo classes:

- `:hover`, for mouse hover
- `:focus`, for keyboard focus

Hope that helps!