# CSS visited links change background color

Tags: css, html

Why doesn't code below work?

```
a:visited {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

taken from: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp

What I am trying to do is have two links pointing at two different points but covering the same box. If either link is visited I want to be notified somehow. Either change background-color or border color.

example:

```
<a id="linkA" href="http://www.w3schools.com/">
  <a id="linkB" href ="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">
   <div id="bix">Change content if either link is visited</div>
 </a>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
#bix {
   border: 3px solid orange;
}

#linkA #bix {
   border: 3px solid green;
}

#linkB #bix {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Problem is that when you inspect the code, #LinkA does not contain #LinkB. How can I make #LinkB inside #LinkA, or any other way to make the #bix react to visits to either #LinkA or #LinkB.

Comment: You can't make LinkB "inside" of LinkA because an HTML `<a>` is allowed to contain only `Inline elements except <a>` — that is, LinkA is not allowed (by spec) to contain the div or the other `<a>`. When you write it that way the browser will re-interpret it to build a valid DOM tree ... probably like `<a id="linkA"> ... </a> <a id="linkB"> ... </a> <div id="bix"> ... </div>` all as siblings.

Comment: @StephenP Yes that is what I noticed. I couldn't figure out why. So I guess there is no way to have a sublink under a lot of links.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't this a:visited css style work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331688/why-doesnt-this-avisited-css-style-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested anchor tags are forbidden in HTML syntax, hence why they're not showing up.

As @beautifulcoder suggested, change the content itself.

```
a:visited > #bix { color: red; }
```

Comment: And that's the problem, nested tags. I guess there is no way to fix this issue and I will have to figure out another way.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a:visited + #bix { ... }
```

You have to change the actual content.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to create a link would be

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">This Will Be The Link</a>
```

Then when this is visited the css to change the color would be

```
a:visited{
    color:blue;/*will change text colour*/
    background-color:yellow;/*will change background colour*/
}
```

The two locations appears redundant to me as it can only go to one location?

Comment: There will be other links on the page that point to these locations.