# Change font weight of a visited link

Tags: css

After a user visits a link, I want the font-weight of the text to go to normal (400).

```
.title-link {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #264464;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.title-link:visited {
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

I read that you can't do this from around 2010+ (https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/), is there any way I can do it still?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't this a:visited css style work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331688/why-doesnt-this-avisited-css-style-work)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using page links perhaps you could use jquery? The only problem being after a page refresh it would go back to being bold.

html

```
<a href='#' class='title-link'>Link</a>
```

jquery

```
$('.title-link').click(function() {
    $('.title-link').css('font-weight', 'normal');
});
```

Seems to work in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z7kmbve7/2/

Comment: Normally links go to a new page, assuming it doesn't and simply changing the font-weight on click is pretty much fruitless here.

Comment: Sorry, didn't reflect that in my answer.