# Chrome doesn't respect <a> color when link is visited

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a strange bug that only occurs on Chrome - visited links ignore the **`color`** attribute and turn black. The chrome inspector shows the computed color as "white", even though it is clearly black.

This is NOT caused by **`:visited`,** as I'm using the same text color, whether it is visited or not.

Here's a **[minimal fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42s8k1vb/1/)**:
You need to visit **[wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org/)** for the bug to appear.

```
<a href="https://www.wikipedia.org/#">This text should be white</a>
<a href="https://www.wikipedia.org/">This text should also be white, but isn't</a>
```

Now, I know this is in part caused by "all: initial", but I need to use this to keep a consistent style in my webextension, since websites override random CSS properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't this a:visited css style work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331688/why-doesnt-this-avisited-css-style-work)

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself, not just on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: Works fine for me, the text is white. Maybe include a screenshot of what you see with your inspector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're having issues with the visited color being overwritten by the browser defaults, are you able to instead set all to unset?

```
#popup {
  all: initial;
}

#popup * {
  all: unset;
  display: block;
}
```

After looking around, not 100% sure why the browser color was overriding the visited anchor, even testing `#popup * {color: initial;}` rule worked, so I'm not sure what underlying mechanism is changing the text color. But looking over at the answer provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15903168/1440950 using unset clears the values as desired

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This issue might be related to the way Chrome handles visited link styling, as there are some browser-specific styles that may override your custom styling.
Try using the " !important " declaration.

```
a:link {
    color: #4b96bb !important;
}
a:visited {
    color: #4b96bb !important; 
}
```